# AEM CQ5 servlet doesn't get called in local environment

Tags: servlets, aem, development-environment

I'm fairly new to AEM development and I'm experiencing some problems in my local environment.
The code I'm using is the same that is currently on the server (where everything works just fine), so I guess there must be some wrong configuration on my side.

So I have this servlet that should be called when trying to download an asset:

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@Service
@Properties({ @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value = "sling/servlet/default"),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET", "POST" }),
    @Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value = "assets") })
public class AssetDownloadServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet
```

It is triggered by the "assets" selector, for example

```
http://localhost:4502/content/.assets.zip?path=content/folder/asset.jpg&_charset_=utf-8
```

Thing is, if I write an URL like this in the bar, it works just fine. The servlet gets called and downloads asset.jpg.

What isn't working is the Javascript code that when the user clicks on a button, builds the URL, puts it in a hidden form and then submits the form. In this case, the servlet doesn't get called at all (I put some breakpoints in debug mode to check) and the following page appears:

```
Status           200
Message          OK
Location         /content/aem/download
Parent Location  /content/aem
Path             /content/aem/download
Referer          http://localhost:4502/content/aem/download.html
ChangeLog        <pre></pre>

Go Back
Modified Resource
Parent of Modified Resource
```

As I said, the code shouldn't be at fault since it works on the server. I just don't even know where to look to understand what I'm doing wrong in local.

**EDIT:**

I opened a related question as the problem may be of another nature: [CQ5 FormPanel sends HTTP POST in Chrome and HTTP GET in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249047/cq5-formpanel-sends-http-post-in-chrome-and-http-get-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you don't have selectors in your url:

```
http://localhost:4502/content/assets.zip?path=content/folder/asset.jpg&_charset_=utf-8
```

Here I can see

- potocol+host: http://localhost:4502
- path to resource: /content/assets
- extension: .zip
- param1: path=content/folder/asset.jpg
- param2: *charset*=utf-8

If you want your servlet be triggered you should add selector (**.assets** between path and extension)

```
http://localhost:4502/content/assets.assets.zip?path=content/folder/asset.jpg&_charset_=utf-8
```

See more at documentation : [Sling url decomposition](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-decomposition.html)

[image: Sling url decomposition:]

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the URL wrong. The actual URL is already http://localhost:4502/content/.assets.zip?path=content/folder/asset.jpg&_charset_=utf-8
(corrected it in the main post)

Comment: @CaterinaBano in this case you dont have correct resource path in the url, try /content.assets.zip or /content/someNode.assets.zip. You should have valid path to resource, /content/ is not valid path

Comment: It was an example, I didn't copy the real url with the actual folder structure of the website. See it as a content/folder/assets.zip?etc...
Anyway, as I said, the URL and the code shouldn't be a problem since they DO work on the server, there must be some configuration on my local that is preventing the servlet from being called, but I don't know where to look to check what it may be.

Comment: go to /system/console/request than request your url and try to find out what filter or servlet is triggered before your custom servlet

Comment: If I try to access system/console/request I get an error: "The requested page was not found. If you are not forwarded in 3 seconds to the Web Console, please click here", and then redirects me to bundles. Is there anything specific I need to do?

Comment: @CaterinaBano sorry add 's' character at the end) /system/console/requests

Comment: Thank you! So, it looks like the request that results in an error is a POST instead of a GET and the SlingPostServlet is being called instead of the AssetDownloadServlet... But how can this be? And why doesn't this happen on the server as well, but just in my local environment?

Comment: @CaterinaBano I see you have mapped servlet to POST and GET methods. You said above that user submit form, in this case POST request is sent to server